# Native JS for Reading HTML5 Custom Data Attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I have learned that HTML5 includes a means to set custom attributes on elements using the data- prefix. However I'm a bit scewered in terms of how to read the properties during a javascript code block. I guess it is my interpretation of how the DOMStringMap is working thats off.

Could someone simplify how to read the properties of the following sample html.

```
<span data-complex-key="howtoRead" data-id="anId">inner</span>
```

Trying following doesnt really work as expected

```
spanEl.dataset['id']                    // straight-forward and result is anId
spanEl.dataset['complex-key']           // undefined
spanEl.dataset['complex']['key']        // throws 'cannot read property of undefined'
spanEl.getAttribute('complex-key')      // there's a null however,
spanEl.getAttribute('data-complex-key') // this variant seems to work
```

Another thing that makes me wonder is, the CSS selectors seems to follow the excact same pattern as to which is i written in the DOM, so why is this not the case with reading from javascript.

For instance, this would match

```
 span[data-complex-key="howtoRead"] { color:green }
```

Appreciate the help, still getting more and more intreaged with the HTML5 Canvas, Video and  local Data Storage :)

Comment: You shouldn't use dashes in the attribute keys BTW,  better opt for camelCased complexKey here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In vanilla-JS, assuming `spanEl` is a reference to the DOM node

```
spanEl.dataset.complexKey
```

will work using the `camelCase` notation (see http://jsbin.com/oduguw/3/edit) when your data attribute contains hypens (`-`) and also

```
spanEl.getAttribute('data-complex-key')
```

will work fine as you already noticed. As a side note, in jQuery you can access to that `data` attribute with

```
$(spanEl).data("complex-key")
```

Comment: Note that in JavaScript `dataset['foo']` is the same as `dataset.foo`, as long as `foo` is a valid identifier.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, it seems to map the data keys in a not-so-straightforward way:

```
console.log(spanEl.dataset);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
//shows:
//DOMStringMap
//  complexKey: "howtoRead"
//  id: "anId"
```

It converts "complex-key" to "complexKey".

While not being completely straightforward, this behavior is defined in the HTML5 spec here:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec//global-attributes.html#dom-dataset

Answer (score 1):

Your first and last method are correct while not using any libraries. However a key with a minus sign is converted to Camel Case, so complex-key becomes complexKey:

```
spanEl.dataset['id']
spanEl.dataset['complexKey']
spanEl.getAttribute('data-complex-key')
```

However, only the last one works in IE up to 9. (I don't know about 10.) The data attributes are nothing else than normal attributes having a naming convention in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
 spanEl.dataSet["complexKey"]
```

//Using jQuery you can try this

```
 $('span').data('complex-key')  // Will give you **howtoRead**

    $('span').data('id')  // Will give you **anId**
```